# SQL server: how to read data from a table still in progress

Tags: sql-server

I have two processes working simultaneously: one is generating a big table, and the other one is to read data from the table generated sequentially. I noticed that the second process has to wait for the first one finished to get started, i.e., the read operation blocks.

My question is that whether there is any way to allow the second process to read data from a table even if it is under working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please, do not suggest using (nolock) for data that is not static.  You may skip records or read records twice.  Not good if it is financial data.

http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/

You should really take a look at my presentation 'How isolated are your sessions' - http://craftydba.com/?page_id=880.

What you are describing above is one of the isolation levels, **read committed** - writers block readers.  It just a fact of life when dealing with transactions (sessions).

There are a bunch more isolations levels.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx

The (NOLOCK) or (READUNCOMMITTED) has three side effect, dirty reads, unrepeatable reads, and phantom reads.

**How about using Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (**RCSI***)?*

It is a version of Read Committed in which readers are not blocked since the version store (tempdb) keeps a copy of the records.  It does not have as much of a impact as SNAPSHOT ISOLATION.  Put in place some type of monitoring on version store growth.

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Like any advice at the transaction level, first test this change in a lower environment.  Have a full understanding of the six isolation levels and how they effect your database & application.